# Custom Section in Sitecore Form Sitecore 9.2

Tags: sitecore-forms, custom-field

I want to create a custom section in sitecore form with CSS ID attribute. And I created that however, the CSS ID value is not getting saved when I save that form. On click of Apply, its retaining value but once I click Save, CSS ID field is getting empty.

Not getting the exact the issue.  Waiting for someone's blessing. Please !

[image]

and this is my model.

[image]

Comment: There is a couple of things you should check:

1. Does your template for the custom field inherits the base template `/Templates/System/Forms/Fields/Field`?
2. Were the bindings in the Property Editor configured? Normally, they are created under this item in core db `/sitecore/client/Applications/Forms/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Property Editor Settings`
3. Try moving the base() calls to the end of you method.

Comment: can you validate that all steps for implementing custom field were achieved ? Like Joao mentioned, you have to play with Sitecore items as well. See Sitecore article here : https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html and if needed, I have also posted an article regarding a much more complex custom field implemention, some snippet might help you : https://razmo.ca/sitecore-form-dynamic-datasource-custom-dropdown-list-field/

Comment: Thanks @JoãoNeto . I have verified and seems good from core db setting and master db as well.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-NicolasG. for providing the ref. surely will go through the article and update.